# Get events in C++ from C# dll which is COM visible

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, event-handling

I have a C# dll which is COM visible and have event handler delegates.
There is no problem to use it in C# program, but I'm struggling to receive events in C++;

This is simple example of C# code:

```
namespace TestCode
{
    public delegate void DataReceivedHandler(object Sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);

    public sealed class DataValidator : IDisposable
    {


        public event DataReceivedHandler DataReceived;

        private void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("### " + e.Value);
            if (DataReceived != null)
            {
                DataReceived(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(e.Status, e.Value, e.RejectedReason));
            }
        }

    }


    public class DataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public DataRecievedStatus Status { get; private set; }
        public int Value { get; private set; }
        public string RejectedReason { get; private set; }

        public DataReceivedEventArgs(DataRecievedStatus status, int value, string rejectedReason)
        {
            this.Status = status;
            this.Value = value;
            this.RejectedReason = rejectedReason;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I use it in C++ example below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "TestCode.dll"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace TestCode;

namespace libTestCode {
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        static DataValidator^ cc = nullptr;
    };  
}
```

The implementation C++ where you see the question marks. It is a place where I don't know how to implement it right:

```
#include "libTestCode.h"

void init()
{
    libTestCode::Class1::cc = gcnew DataValidator();

    libCashCode::Class1::cc->DataReceived += gcnew ?????????

    return NULL;
 }
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Pay a visit to your local library or book store to get ahead.  You are not actually using C++ and not actually using COM.  This kind of gratuitous usage of *static* is going to get you into big trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that adding event listener is almost the same as in C#

Only the implementation c++ file should be edited

```
void init()
{
    libTestCode::Class1::cc = gcnew DataValidator();

    DataReceivedHandler ^handler = gcnew DataReceivedHandler(myHandler);

    libCashCode::Class1::cc->DataReceived += handler;

}

void myHandler(Object ^obj, DataReceivedEventArgs ^eventArgs) 
{

}
```

My error was that I forget to use "^" symbol for parameters in myHandler.